# stylesheets in highlight js are refused for being wrong MIME type

Tags: angular, highlightjs

I have an Angular 16 app that uses highlightjs.  I technically installed the `ngx-highlightjs` library for Angular, but the stylesheets keep being refused by the browser because it says their MIME types are `text/HTML`.  The code I use with highlight js is highlighted, however it seems to look the same no matter what I switch to as if it's defaulting to a particular set of rules.  I have it setup in my `main.ts` file like this

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    /* other stuff */
    {
      provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: <HighlightOptions>{
        coreLibraryLoader: () => import('highlight.js/lib/core'),
        lineNumbersLoader: () => import('ngx-highlightjs/line-numbers'),
        languages: {
          xml: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/xml'),
          css: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/css')
        },
        themePath: '../node_modules/highlight.js/styles/a11y-dark.css'
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

I even added the stylesheet to the `styles` array in my `angular.json` file and I still get this error.  Does anybody know how this can be fixed?